# Google Colab is so slow while reading images from Google Drive

Tags: keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I have my own dataset for a deep learning project. I uploaded that into Google Drive and linked it to a Colab page. But Colab could read only 2-3 images in a second, where my computer can dozens of them. (I used imread to read images.)

There is no speed problem with model compiling process of **keras**, but only with reading images from Google Drive. Does anybody know a solution? Someone suffered of this problem too, but it's still unsolved: [Google Colab very slow reading data (images) from Google Drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929888/google-colab-very-slow-reading-data-images-from-google-drive) (I know this is kind of a duplication of the question in the link, but I reposted it because it is still unsolved. I hope this is not a violation of Stack Overflow rules.)

Edit: The code piece that I use for reading images:

```
def getDataset(path, classes, pixel=32, rate=0.8):
    X = []
    Y = []

    i = 0
    # getting images:
    for root, _, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            imagePath = os.path.join(root, file)
            className = os.path.basename(root)

            try:
                image = Image.open(imagePath)
                image = np.asarray(image)
                image = np.array(Image.fromarray(image.astype('uint8')).resize((pixel, pixel)))
                image = image if len(image.shape) == 3 else color.gray2rgb(image)
                X.append(image)
                Y.append(classes[className])
            except:
                print(file, "could not be opened")

    X = np.asarray(X, dtype=np.float32)
    Y = np.asarray(Y, dtype=np.int16).reshape(1, -1)

    return shuffleDataset(X, Y, rate)
```

Comment: Can you provide the code you use to load the data?

Comment: @Solvalou I added it to the question description.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'd like to provide a more detailed answer about what unzipping the files actually looks like. This is the best way to speed up reading data because unzipping the file into the VM disk is SO much faster than reading each file individually from Drive.

Let's say you have the desired images or data in your local machine in a folder Data. Compress Data to get Data.zip and upload it to Drive.

Now, mount your drive and run the following command:

```
!unzip "/content/drive/My Drive/path/to/Data.Zip" -d "/content"
```

Simply amend all your image paths to go through /content/Data, and reading your images will be much much faster.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to upload your file to [GitHub](https://github.com/) then clone it to Colab. It can reduce my training time from 1 hour to 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Upload zip files to the drive. After transferring to colab unzip them. File copy overhead is cumbersome therefore you shouldn't copy masses of files instead copy a single zip and unzip.